# Manipulate DateTimeType in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I want to give some default values to the hours and minutes on symfony via DateTimeType. I want that I can select hours only between 8h to 18h:

```
add('daterdv', DateTimeType::class, array('label'=>'Date :'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify hour range use 'hours' option like

```
->add('daterdv', DateTimeType::class, array(
        'hours'=> array(8, 18)
    ));
```

But note that 'This option is only relevant when the widget option is set to choice.' according to Symfony documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much mister Valentin